# Why are some KeyEvents not working in certain applications?

Tags: java, awt, key-bindings, keyevent, keycode

The title actually hits it. To specify:

I've tried to work with some KeyEvents while having a game on fullscreen. But for some reason, some of them work (like TAB, Enter, characters (A-Z)), and some others don't, like the arrow keys or the DELETE-key.

What's even more confusing is that `VK_LEFT` and `VK_RIGHT` function as if they were the numpad keys, while the documentation says the oposite. But `VK_KP_LEFT` and the other three as well do not seem to work at all (while having that addressed game on full screen), independant from whether NUM is enabled or not.

I used `Thread.sleep(300)` to hold the key a bit before releasing and to wait between consecutive keystrokes.

So, has anyone an explanation or assumption on why this could be? And is it possible, to get this fixed without setting up custom key bindings?

I'd be really glad to know.

Comment: Please share some code segment where these keys are not working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it may be some problem with your code and not the Java KeyEvents. Please share some code.

Comment: _"And is it possible, to get this fixed without setting up custom key bindings"_ - What's wrong with using key binding?